# When switchport port-security violation protect( or restrict) is configured , how many times can the security policy be breached?

Tags: cisco, switch, mac-address, cisco-commands, port-security

The switchport port-security violation shutdown , shuts the port (err-disabled) when the policy is violated. But, for restrict and protect modes there isn't a mention of shutting a port down. So, can the policy be violated unlimited number of times when a switch port is configured with :
switchport port-security violation restrict(or protect)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the restrict and protect modes can be violated any number of times without shutting down the port since they are not designed to do that; they will drop packets with unknown source addresses:

See [Configuring the Port Security Violation Mode on a Port](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj8ib7YzZrKAhWISiYKHWbzDWoQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cisco.com%2Fc%2Fen%2Fus%2Ftd%2Fdocs%2Fswitches%2Flan%2Fcatalyst6500%2Fios%2F12-2SX%2Fconfiguration%2Fguide%2Fbook%2Fport_sec.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGniMS0_1eavbameyhIPccDtQG7Dw&sig2=bS8h3Aodj-0DGoWqBqzOAQ&cad=rja) on page 62-6:

> - **protect**—Drops packets with unknown source addresses until you remove a sufficient number of secure MAC addresses to drop below the 
>     maximum value.
> - **restrict**—Drops packets with unknown source addresses until you remove a sufficient number of secure MAC addresses to drop below the 
>     maximum value and causes the SecurityViolation counter to increment.
> - **shutdown**—Puts the interface into the error-disabled state immediately and sends an SNMP trap notification.